# Appended objects have bad quality

Tags: materials, faces, append

I am recreating an ancient settlement with Blender, and to make my life easier, I modeled several types of ceramic vases with procedural materials on a separate file, which I appended (not linked, since I need them to have different materials) to my main file both via the asset browser and File > Append.

[image: Set of ceramic items in render view on their original file]

[image: Ceramic vase with procedural material in render view on its original file]

The problem is that these appended objects have very bad quality. It seems the edges are "jittery" and when I switch to render view, I can see all the edges, as if the faces were floating and detached from each other. This doesn't happen in their original file, as seen in the image above. This happens with all the objects and all materials (including the default white) in the main file.

[image: The same type of vase, isolated in render view in the main file]

Is there any way to fix this?

EDIT: Here's a link to a [folder with both files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p8Qsp6WlV29E05mCE9ZjohdgMtWNvjmA?usp=sharing). If everything is correct the ceramic objects should be in the asset browser of the main file (tfm_send) already, but if they aren't, appending any of the objects through File > Append gave me the same results.

Comment: i cannot really believe that, because AFAIK it is a true copy if you append it. Are you sure that it isn't caused by material? If you really shall help you, you should provide a blend file with the original model and tell us the steps to recreate your problem.

Comment: It also looks like the "good" version is _Material Preview_ or _Eevee_ while the "bad" seems to be _Rendered View_ with _Cycles_, but that's just a guess since you do not provide any information on that. If these are two different shading modes / render engines, are you sure the "good" would still look good if you view it in the same shading mode as the appended object? Because as @Chris asked, I suspect problems with the either the material here or with the geometry of the object which are simply not visible in _Eevee_.

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: They're both using _Cycles_ with GPU Compute. The only difference is the lighting of the scenes, and I just checked but it still happens if I use the same default HDRI on the "bad" file. I will try to share the files.

Comment: "*not linked, since I need them to have different materials*" Sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you can have them linked and still change the materials, depending on how they are linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've painstakingly gone through your file, and found what was wrong with it.

1. Your objects are *very* far away from the world origin, which is known to cause issues;

[image]

2. Your `Clip End` was set *very* high, which is also known to cause graphical issues (see the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#depth-buffer-glitches));

[image]

3. The `Cycles` `Feature Set` [`Experimental`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/cycles/features.html) won't help either, with rendering, as it may include bugs (as described in the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/cycles/features.html))

I hope this brings some clarity as to why Blender behaves the way it does, in your file.

Comment: This was it! I moved everything closer to the world origin and lowered the Clip end distance and it was fixed. Thank you so much (and sorry for the pain caused), I'm very new to Blender and don't think I would've figured it out on my own.

Comment: @Hellwyr It's something common to all 3D programs. Only if you know it might cause a problem, you can look for it. Happy to help!